# Grunt usemin and cache manifest

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I'm building an angular app with grunt which uses cache manifest.
My problem is that after concatenation and minification of all my js files in one, the manifest.cfm doesn't get rewritten and that makes the paths in it incorrect.

Here is some of my Gruntfile.js :

```
    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
// concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
// additional tasks can operate on them
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    flow: {
      html: {
        steps: {
          js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
          css: ['cssmin']
        },
        post: {}
      }
    }
  }
},

// Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html','<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.tpl.html', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/templates{,*/}*.tpl.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/icons-app']
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hand-writing the new paths in manifest.cfm before building. I'm not sure there is actually a way to get it automatically rewritten by any grunt task.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is a bit old, but I just solved something similar, and could not find many answers to help. Your best bet is to continue using filerev and use a grunt manifest creator like [grunt-manifest](https://github.com/gunta/grunt-manifest). You want the file names to change when they are updated (with filerev) so the manifest file will change as well. That is the only way the application cache will know it needs to update.

After you install grunt-manifest, a config like this in your grunt file should do what your asking:

```
manifest: {
 generate: {
   options: {
     basePath: 'app/',
     network: ['*'],
     preferOnline: true
   },
   src: [
     'scripts/*.js',
     'styles/*.css',
     'images/*.*',
     'views/{,*/}*.html'
   ],
   dest: 'dist/cache.manifest'
 }
}
```

More Info: http://bnlconsulting.com/blog/the-browser-cache-and-angular

Answer (score 0):

you can comment the "filerev" task form your grunt build one. This will spare you the rewriting after a new build.

Comment: also, a grunt task exists for this : https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-manifest-generator

Answer (score 0):

Maybe necromacing this thread but there is: https://github.com/JoshSchreuder/grunt-manifest-generator

It will scan a given html file and automatically include all javascript/css/html files within.